# Having 2 seperate infinite Loops

Tags: python, loops

I want to recieve the keypresses of the User using `msvcrt.getch`, while I also want the program to write something to the screen every second. Thats my code:

```
while True:
    key = getch()        

    print("one second")
    sleep(1)
```

When I run it, it only continues writing `one second` to the screen when I press something.

Comment: Use multiple threads or processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msvcrt also has a method called [kbhit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit) which is true if there is a char waiting to be read. So you can call that before reading the char.

```
while True:
    if kbhit():
        key = getch()

    print("one second")
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist very true, but as it stands I think it answers the OP's question. Otherwise something like skymon's answer would be better

Comment: I think OP agrees with you. Also, given how Python threads work, skymon's answer may not work quite as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Threading, e.g. like this:

```
import threading
import time

def input_action():
    while True:
        key = getch()

def print_action():
    while True:
        print("one second")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_thread = threading.Thread(target=input_action)
    print_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_action)
    input_thread.start()
    print_thread.start()
```